# How to provide converter for Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm pretty new to spring integration and have next problem. I have next integration:

```
<int:channel id="channel"/>

<int:gateway id="api" service-interface="com.example.ApiGateway">
    <int:method name="getResponse"
                payload-expression="T(java.lang.String).format('${url}', #args[0])"
                request-channel="channel"/>
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway http-method="GET" url-expression="payload"
                           request-channel="channel"
                           expected-response-type="com.example.Response"/>
```

Gateway:

```
public interface ApiGateway {
    Response getResponse(final String id);
}
```

Where response is small entity:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response
{
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
...
}
```

Then I wrote unit test for this integration but it always fails with

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type com.example.Response
```

I've tried to add `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to `message-converters` in `int-http:outbound-gateway` but it's not working.

So my question how to set converter from json to my Response?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran a test and it worked fine for me - you don't need to configure a custom converter, the jackson converter is provided by default.

Did you add the jackson jars to the classpath?

Comment: Yes I did, maybe something wrong with my test. I used this example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/testing/externalgateway

Comment: I specified a custom message-converter, which is similar to StringHttpMessaageConverter, and overwritten writeIntenal to suppress body. But this converter is getting applied for all other types of requests too, where custom message-converters is not specified.  Any idea why?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 4 year old answers; ask a new question and show your code and configuration.

Comment: sadly, I cant ask questions anymore. But I can explain here - I have to call external service for different endpoints. there are http-outbound gateways inside chain with header enricher etc. Now one of the request -  url="${GBAURL}/rest/sign/v3/{idAndStatus}" and has <int-http:uri-variable name="idAndStatus" expression="payload" />. Now the extermal service, doesnt like body. But my controller is sending - public String gidAsComplete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {. paylod=id+"/done".gGateway.setIdAsComplete(payload)..} so body is getting passed. I want to stop this, only for this endpoint.

Comment: I've sorted my problem in the gateway interface - use @payload !

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like your server doesn't return the proper `Content-Type` HTTP header.

That is how the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` works for conversion something from the `new MediaType("application", "*+json")` to convert into a desired POJO.

If it returns only simple `text/plain`, you don't have choice unless receive a simple `String` and use `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` afterwards.